# Issue with ios devicing playing pageview controller based application and the difference between simulator results and ios device

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios-simulator, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app which has tableview as index and then when you click on an item it goes to that item with navigation bar displaying the item's name correctly. From then on, you can flip the pages using pageview  controller. and the title changes accordingly.

Works fine in simulator no matter how much you play around. However on device there is a weird issue. When I click on first item, everything is fine but when you flip the page it changes title perfectly as well, however on the page turned if you click on the page to either scroll down or just touch it for any reason, (the title changes which means index changes on touch only while clicking at the second recipe.)

Note : this does not happen in simulator nor does it happen when you are viewing first item selecting from index but only when you turn the page.

1) how can I solve this, or
2) any handler which can handle uipageviewcontroller's flipping events, I have referred to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html with no real luck.